# How to draw shape like ellipse and line and calculate area on gesture

Tags: android

[image: Philips Lumify]

Take a reference of Philips Lumify app in playstore android.Please help me out to generate this shape.

Answer (score 0):

create [custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) and and override `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method, you must [draw your shape](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) inside it like so:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);

   if(touched)
       canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, mPaint);
}
```

then handle gesture inside `onTouchEvent` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();

    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touched = true;
            centerX = x;
            centerY = y;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // calculate radius
            radius = Math.abs(centerX - x);
            break;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            touched = false;
            break;
    }
    // call next frame
    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
```

see also [canvas.drawOval](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawOval) method.